# How could I merge topics from different kafka clusters into a single central cluster?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to merge data from different edge nodes. All of these edge nodes have a local kafka server running in order to be robustness against any network problems. I also have a central kafka cluster running which processes all incoming messages. From here, I would like to replicate topic "events" which exists both in local cluster A and local cluster B, into a central cluster C.

I have tried to use confluent replicator in order to replicate topics across clusters, and merge them into a single cluster. However, I wasn't able to replicate a topic into an already existing topic. Without any pre/suffixes in the "topic.rename.format" option in Kafka; the connect replicator will throw me the following error:

```
ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=replicator_test-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.NewReplicatorAdminClient tried to access method 'void org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry.<init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry$ConfigSource, boolean, boolean, java.util.List, org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry$ConfigType, java.lang.String)' (io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.NewReplicatorAdminClient is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader @51c7d472; org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ConfigEntry is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I'm using the following replicator configuration:

```
{
"name": "replicator_test",
"config": {
    "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max":1,
    "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
    "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
    "src.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.1.215:9092",
    "dest.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"192.168.1.157:9092",
    "topic.whitelist":"events_test,_schemas",
    "topic.rename.format":"${topic}",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": 1,
    "dest.topic.replication.factor": 1,
    "src.kafka.timestamps.topic.replication.factor": 1,
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "192.168.1.157:9092"
}}
```

Note that the replicator is running on the edge node and that I am overwritting the producer bootstrap server. I also noted that the original topic also gets created on the destination cluster, but no messages appear here.

Also open for different approaches to collect edge data and send it to a central server in a robust + scalable way.

Comment: What specific problems were you having with Replicator? It should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Replicator, MirrorMaker, or your own home-grown consumer and producer are all valid options (and the only way to do so).

Confluent offers [Cluster Linking](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/cluster-linking/index.html) in latest releases, but this (and Replicator) are Enterprise features, if you are not a paying customer.

Comment: please see above :)

Comment: `IllegalAccessError` is typically a JVM issue, unrelated to the tool being used. For example, Confluent does not support Java 17, so you'd need to downgrade to 11.

Comment: Then how does that explain the fact that it can run when the topic is actually renamed? I am only getting issues for when topics aren't renamed.

Comment: Maybe the method uses reflection or something the JVM doesn't allow when topics are renamed? The method shows its trying to construct an AdminClient, but Replicator isn't open source, so I can't answer that